# Error During Recheck torrent

Tags: bittorrent

During Recheck Torrent file, I got **"Error :check :Data Error (CRC)"** this Error 
how I am Solve this Error????
! http://postimg.org/image/43uhy223v/

Comment: The data is failing the CRC check.  I would just download the data again.

Comment: @Ramhound its Displaying Same Erro...

Comment: Sounds like the source file is corrupt.  I would try a different torrent of the same file.